# Google App Engine - Datastore Admin Not Working

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, datastore-admin

I am simply trying to access the datastore admin for myapp at: https://appengine.google.com/datastore/admin?&app_id=s~placingliterature&version_id=jan2015.383591079272347357

But when I go there, the main portion of the screen is blank, although all the menus are still there.

I am using the owner of the account for this.

Also, This is not working on multiple peoples computers in my office, not just mine.

It did work at one point, but now it does not.

Any suggestions?
Has anyone seen this before

Comment: Does it work when you go to https://ah-builtin-python-bundle-dot-placingliterature.appspot.com/_ah/datastore_admin/?app_id=s~placingliterature&adminconsolecustompage (assuming `placingliterature` is the id of your app)?

Comment: Yes, it does work at: https://ah-builtin-python-bundle-dot-placingliterature.appspot.com/_ah/datastore_admin/?app_id=s~placingliterature&adminconsolecustompage

Comment: Make it an answer so I can accept it

Comment: Well, this wasn't really an answer, this just proves that it is something with your computer (and the computers of multiple people who tested it) - you can find the same url as an iframe src in the source code of https://appengine.google.com/datastore/admin?&app_id=s~placingliterature&version_id=jan2015.383591079272347357 so it looks like for some reason your browser (or any security add-on) blocks the loading of the iframe.

Comment: ok well thank you very much either way

Comment: I had this problem in the past, and I think it was caused by disabling third party cookies.  Try a different browser and see if it works or enable third party cookies.